# How to implement Bilinear pairing using Miracl c++

Tags: c++, security, cryptography, pairing

I want to implement a Bilinear pairing for my project.  **Can anyone give some idea (or code in c
++) about how we can implement using Miracl library in C++.**
**An admissible bilinear pairing e: G1 × G1 → G2 has
the three unique properties for (g, h) ∈R (G1)2:

1. Bilinearity: satisfies e(gα, hβ) = e(g, h)^αβ for (α, β) ∈R (Z∗p)
2. Nondegeneracy: ensures e(g, g) != 1, where 1 ∈ G2 is identity element;
3. computability: the existence of an efficient algorithm to calculate e(g, h).**

Comment: Use NTL library, that can handle gropus, etc.